# Use of try and except in this python in this program

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, except

Can you please tell me why try and except is used in the following code?
Why score=-1? I mean why only -1

```
inp = input('Enter score: ')
    try:
        score = float(inp)
    except:
        score = -1

if score > 1.0 or score < 0.0:
       print ('Bad score')
   elif score > 0.9:
     print ('A')
   elif score > 0.8:
     print ('B')
   elif score > 0.7:
     print ('C')
   elif score > 0.6:
     print ('D')
   else:
     print ('F')
```

Cant we use the following code which has no try and except commands.

```
 score = float(input('Enter score: '))
   if score > 1.0 or score < 0.0:
       print ('Bad score')
   elif score > 0.9:
       print ('A')
   elif score > 0.8:
       print ('B')
   elif score > 0.7:
       print ('C')
   elif score > 0.6:
       print ('D')
   else:
       print ('F')
```

Comment: @elegent: er, `if not(0. <= score <= 1.):`?

Comment: @HughBothwell: yes :) thanks you are right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user enters something that cannot be converted into a float, the program would stop with an exception. The `try` catches this and uses a default value.

This would work:

```
inp = input('Enter score: ')
try:
    score = float(inp)
except ValueError:
    print('bad score')
```

Your version:

```
score = float(input('Enter score: '))
if score > 1.0 or score < 0.0:
     print ('Bad score')
```

would throw a `ValueError` on this line `float(input('Enter score: '))` if the user would enter `abc` for example. Your program would stop before you can print `Bad score'`.

Answer (score 2):

The try-except block is there because the user might enter something that's not a valid float. E.g., "none". In that case, python will throw a `ValueError`. Using an unrestricted `except` is very bad style, so the code should have read

```
try:
    score = float(inp)
except ValueError:
    score = -1
```

It's set to `-1` because the rest of the code treats negative scores as illegal inputs, so anything illegal will get the point across without terminating the program.

Comment: You mean, should have been `except ValueError:`?